# Creating Drop Down List of Layers for ModelBuilder Tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, layers, parameters

In ModelBuilder I require the user select 1 of 5 feature class layers as the initial feature class to run the rest of the model on. The selected layer is to be then fed into a clipping tool as the Input Feature

How do I create a drop-down list of layers in the tool selected from ones I have set the file path for?

I want to have 5 feature class layers selectable as the input for the clipping tool.

ArcMap 10.2

Comment: Are all your input layers held in the same workspace?

Comment: the layers are held in a Feature Dataset within a Geodatabase connection.

Comment: Does it _need_ to be a dynamic list, read from a workspace? Or is it the same 5 over and over? If that's the case you can make and hard code a list on inputs

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the type of functionality you are asking for is possible in pure ModelBuilder environment. To create a parameter that offers up lists you would have to build a [script tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-creating-script-tools.htm) that feeds into a python script. If you want even more control then a [python toolbox script](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm) is probably a better solution.